# How to pass a json object from the jsp part of a jsp page to the javascript part i.e from server side to client side?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

I have a JSON object in the JSP side say "names", whose contents are:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName": "John",  "lastName": "Doe" },
        { "firstName": "Anna",  "lastName": "Smith" },
        { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" }
    ]
}
```

I want to pass this JSON object and its contents to a the javascript part in the same page. I have tried usual method of passing variables i.e

```
var v = <%= variable %>;
```

But that did not work. I would like to know if there is a working alternative.

Comment: in which format you have at java side?? Is it a list of map or object kind of thing??

Comment: Are you trying to pass from Servlet to JSP to Javascript ?

Comment: Iam trying to pass if from the jsp page's java code section to the client side javascript section.

Comment: Why do you want to assign variable value like this, this isn't a good practise.

Answer (score 0):

In your .jsp you can do this:

```
<script>
var myString = ${YourJSONString};
</script>
<body onload="myinitfunc(myString);"> </body>
```

**OR**

In your .jsp you can also do:

```
<body onload="${YourJSONString}"> </body>
```

To escape single quotes coming in from JSON use:

```
<body onload="${fn:escapeXml(YourJSONString)}"> </body>
```

Comment: It didnot work. What i want to do is pass my json object to my script section like when we normally pass a variable to the script section. Is there an easy straight forward way to do this ?